# How to make d3-diagram visualization from json-array working?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a problem with a d3 visualization (bar chart) that doesn't work.

Instead of loading the data from a CSV file like in the tutorials on the d3 page (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304), I want it to load from a JSON-array.
Though I'm not sure why it doesn't seem like it loads at all. Can be something when I added the time parse, or placed the `x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));` outside a CSV load data snippet.

Thank you for your help!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


var data = [{date:"1999-06-23" ,value:1},{date:"1999-06-24" ,value:2},{date:"1999-06-28" ,value:3},{date:"1999-06-29" ,value:4},{date:"1999-06-30" ,value:5}];


var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
});

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 956)
  .attr("height", 360)
  margin = {top: 50, right: 100, bottom: 50, left: 50},
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.05);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

g.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");



</script>
```

```css
 .axis {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
 }

 .axis path,
 .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of the problems:

1. Your reference to D3 is v3. However, your code uses v4.
2. You are defining the axes generators before defining the scales.
3. You are not translating the axes.

Besides that, there is no such a thing as "JSON array". That's just an array. You probably meant *hardcoded data*

Here is the working code:

```js
var data = [{
  date: "1999-06-23",
  value: 1
}, {
  date: "1999-06-24",
  value: 2
}, {
  date: "1999-06-28",
  value: 3
}, {
  date: "1999-06-29",
  value: 4
}, {
  date: "1999-06-30",
  value: 5
}];

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.value = +d.value;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 956)
  .attr("height", 360);

var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.05);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
})]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
  .ticks(10);

g.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Value ($)");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```